# Vaadin flow AppLayout and full height grid as content

Tags: vaadin-flow

I'm currently porting over a vaadin 8 app and wish to use the AppLayout for this. So far everthing is, ok, with one exception.

The AppLayout does not support a full height gri/tree grid as it's main content, as documented in the component guide.

Any work arround this nasty problem?

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/app-layout/#scrolling-behavior

Setting the grid too 100% height and the content to 100% height gives me two scrollbars

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To support full height components within App Layout, set its height to 100%.

See the (now updated) documentation for App Layout: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/app-layout/#scrolling-behavior

Comment: We should definitely have an example of these two use cases.

Comment: I can't get it working. The AppLayout has no method for settings it's height. and `    getElement().setAttribute("height", "100%");` on the constructor seems not to help in my case.

As content I have a Div which the contains a HorizontalLayout and the Grid

Comment: Okay, I didn’t realize `AppLayout` does not implement `HasSize`. So you’ll have to resort to the Element API, which should work. I think the problem now is the sizing of the content elements, that they the exceed height of the parent. Check your expand/flex ratios.

Comment: Oh, also, don't set the `height` _attribute_. You need to set the inline style: `getElement().getStyle().set("height", "100%");`

Comment: So far it does not work, still two scrollbars, I will make a minimal project to help find the problem

Comment: If your Div has height:100%, and then you have a horizontal layout and a grid with height: 100% inside it, then the grid will exceed the height of the layout by the height of the horizontal layout. You need to convert the div into a flex container (or use vertical layout) and then allow the grid to expand/grow to take all the remaining space (left after the horizontal layout height).

Comment: Thanks, now works as expected